# Ember.js - How to clear the form data after saving the record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember App Kit.  I have a form that takes a student name and I can save the data into a database without any problem.  The problem is the data (student name) retains on the form whenever I get transition back to this route (`http://localhost:8000/#/students/new`) from another page.  If I refresh the screen, then the data will be cleared out and I will get a fresh form. What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I decide not to save or add the record and go to see the list of students, I see an empty record on screen.  That record is not in the database though.  How can I prevent that?

```
//--------------------------------------------
// Controller

var StudentsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        var newSystem = this.store.createRecord('student');
        this.set('newStudent', newStudent);
        this._super();
    },
    actions: {
        acceptChanges: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.get('newStudent').save().then(function(student){
                self.transitionToRoute('students');
            });
        }
    }
});

export default StudentsNewController;

//--------------------------------------------    
// Model

var Student = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    major: DS.belongsTo('major')

});

export default Student;

//--------------------------------------------    
// Template

    <form  {{action 'updateSystem' on="submit"}}>
        <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label>Student Name</label>
                    {{input value=newStudent.name size="50"}}
                </div>
                <button {{action 'acceptChanges'}}>Add</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is the information in the form saved as an auto complete, or is the data entered into the form input such that if you click `Add` a Student will be added with that information?

Comment: A user has to enter the input (no auto completion) and clicks "Add" to save.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to setup the controller in you route ([here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/)) instead of using the `init` method in the controller. It's one of the routes responsibilities.

I think the problem is that you assume that every time you transition to the  `StudentsNewRoute` a new `StudentsNewController` is created, and thus the `init` method is called.

The truth is Ember creates the controller once and changes it's content based on the `model` and the `setupController` hooks. So the `init` method of the controller it's called once and you end up with the same record every time you transition to the route.

To solve this you'd do something like this:

```
var StudentsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    newStudent: null,
    actions: {
        acceptChanges: function () {
            this.get('newStudent').save().then((student) => {
                this.transitionToRoute('students');
            });
        }
    }
});
//--------------------------------------------
var StudentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('student');
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('newStudent', model);
    },
});
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I followed your suggestion but I got this error:

Assertion failed: Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('newStudent', <(subclass of DS.Model):ember488:null>) to the 'content' property of object proxy <appkit@controller:students/new::ember541>: its 'content' is undefined. 

The file structure is:

controllers/students/new.js
routes/students/new.js

Why would it complain about that?

Comment: I got the error above but fixed by adding "newStudent" into the controller.  The form is clear after a record is saved or coming back to this route.  THANKS!

Comment: Good solution, however what do you do if your form is filled out by the user through bindings on the controller and not pre-populated by the model? Is it also appropriate to use `setupController` to clear these bound variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
 actions: {
    acceptChanges: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.get('newStudent').save().then(function(student){
            self.set('newStudent','');
            self.transitionToRoute('students');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stakoov. Once I used the code provided by edpaez above, the form clears up every time I go there.

Comment: **@Stakoov**, your code doesn't seem to work for me.  The page loads in blank.

Comment: then tray to set newStudent to null